# How to add a Gmail Account to a android device through java code?

Tags: java, android, android-account

I want to add a **gmail account** in to a android device using my application.

in my application having **2 Edit Text**,

Username(for getting username like user1@gmail.com) n

Password(for getting password like *********)

and have **a button**

AddAccount(for onclick listener)

when i click the button it should add a gmail account in to gmail account.

(By the way i have done this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227274/how-to-add-programmatically-a-custom-account-in-android) answered by **ben** and working well, But its not working for add a gmail account).

plz give suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean **Bean** 's answer worked for any other account except `Gmail`????

Comment: Which means from the Bean's answeradd a new category of account like Google, FaceBook.The selection of accounts will shown "MYPACKAGE" as a account type.

Comment: Finally i understood it cant allowed by gmail bcz of security reason. so Beter we use this code to add an account in android device.  **AccountManager acm = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
        acm.addAccount("com.google", null, null, null, GmailLogin.this, 
        null, null);**

Comment: @Mohanraj Any idea why it cannot be done for gmail. Any link for documentation/details regarding this?

Comment: @user1429322 gmail won't allow to add like due to security reason. but it allows to reroute the device's add gmail account window. that's a only way to do from my experience. :)