# How do I create an Android App with an account on user's device ?

Tags: android, user-accounts

For example, apps like Facebook, Whatsapp have a separate account on the device. I want to have a similar behaviour. 
[image]

Comment: See the Android doc => https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html

Comment: Please take a look at this stack post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227274/how-to-add-programmatically-a-custom-account-in-android/39686087#39686087](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227274/how-to-add-programmatically-a-custom-account-in-android/39686087#39686087).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the AccountManager
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

[How to add programmatically a custom account in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227274/how-to-add-programmatically-a-custom-account-in-android)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for :)